# Fitting spline to data with duplicate x using scipy (Python)

Tags: machine-learning, regression, interpolation, curve-fitting, spline

I am trying to fit spline on my data having 5700 data samples (with duplicate x values ie. x: horizontal axis) using 'interp1d' function from package 'scipy' in python. I tried with lower order spline (k=1) and with the quadratic spline(k=2), cubic spline (k=3).
And I am shocked to witness the weird response of 'spline' on my data.Although spline at 'k=1' made some sense but is ridiculously overfitting it(quadratic and cubic spline performed too bad).In my first trial, I used Polynomial fitting to fit the data and results were encouraging.
I was expecting spline fitting will give results better than what I got with polynomial fitting.[This is the result with splines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYvrl.png).
Please suggest me, where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  a data set has separate uniquely valued points for each X value, the effective weighting for each data point is 1.0.  If however a single data point in that data set is doubled, or copied, once that single data point has an effective weight of 2.0.

If all data points in a data set are copied once, each point then has the same effective weight of 2.0 - that is, all data points will have the same weight.

If some data points in this data set have unique X values and some appear more than once, one approach is to average the Y values for the "duplicate" data points so that each point again has an effective weight of 1.0.  This can sometimes work in the specific case I describe.

Comment: Thanks James, I removed duplicates with their avg. and now spline on k=1 is same as k=2 is same as k=3.
Should I not expect the performance of 'Quadratic', 'Cubic' spline better than 'Linear'? or there is some other problem?

Comment: I suggest a few simple tests easily programmed.  Extract a smaller data set with the values for min(x), max(x), mean(x) plus a few other points, which should work as expected.  Then try a data set with every 100th data point, then every 10th, and then one with every other data point.  The analysis is to determine the effect of the number of data points on the results.  This should take very littile time to perform, and should be informative.  My suspicion from looking at your graph is that the splines are working correctly and smoothing the noise in the data.